# Block access to docker for a specific IP address

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, docker

Trying to do this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s (some-ip-address) -j DROP
```

But the ip address still connects to a application running in a docker service. I suspect this is because docker bypasses the firewall.

How can I block the IP address?

**Edit, clarification:**

I have docker running on a server. I have a PC that connects to one of the services running on the server. The PC needs to be blocked from connecting.

Comment: do you mean the container running on docker engine? or the docker itself?

Comment: `-D` is deleting a rule, not adding one. You need to insert the rule at the correct position.

Comment: @ZarehKasparian I mean block an IP from connecting to the host where docker is running. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider sorry I messed up when copying from the command history. I have updated the question.

Comment: The statement is the same. You need to insert the rule at the correct position. Appending it to the end of course doesn't work.

Comment: I was following this "tutorial": https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-block-an-ip-on-my-linux-server/. Okay, so `-I` will make the rule work? Rules at the "beginning" take precedence?

Answer (score 0):

Probably several things happening. You are appending the rule (`-A`) which means the docker rules may have already accepted the packet. You are applying to the INPUT table, and there's a DOCKER-USER table designated for these rules. And if you try to do port filtering, the NAT rules will likely break your logic. Here's an example that inserts a rule at the top of the DOCKER-USER table to drop traffic on a specific interface that isn't from an approved subnet to a specific port:

```shell
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp \
  -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 8080 -j DROP
```

Comment: Care to explain the flags here? Why would I want to specify interface, tcp, port when I want to block all traffic from the IP?

Comment: @birgersp The above is an example with all the options, and you can pick which ones make sense for you. I've come across too many questions that omit details that dramatically change the answer, so I just provide everything and you can ignore the parts that don't apply to your scenario.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me but okay. Thanks for the example. The conclusion is that I should remove the `-A` and use `-I`  and `DOCKER-USER` arguments to the iptables command?

Comment: @birgersp If all you're blocking is a single IP, then yes.